# Using a python wrapper, how can one tell if a model is finished being trained in bigquery ml?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to train a model via bigquery ml. I'd like to have my process wait till the model is complete before moving on to the next logical step. The google client returns a query id that I can use to locate the model (if it exists). Is there any feature/tool that can be used to accomplish listening for the model's completion cleanly or should I just have a loop with a pause and a try/exempt statement checking till the model exists?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.